# How can I use useRef when using ScrollTigger in React?

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I'm using Gsap's ScrollTigger to develop horizontal scrolling.

If a ref is passed when using Gsap's toArray, only the ref of the last element that uses the ref will be referenced. How can I pass all used refs to toArray?

Is only className used as an argument to toArray? Or is there another way to implement horizontal scrolling differently?

```js
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const Home = () => {
  const panelRef = useRef(null);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const sections = gsap.utils.toArray(panelRef); // If you pass a ref, only the last ref will be referenced
    gsap.to(sections, {
      xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: containerRef.current,
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        end: '+=3500', 
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container ref={containerRef}>
      <Panel className="panel" ref={panelRef}>
        ONE
      </Panel>
      <Panel className="panel" ref={panelRef}>
        TWO
      </Panel>
      <Panel className="panel" ref={panelRef}>
        THREE
      </Panel>
    </Container>
  );
};
const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: max-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;
const Panel = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
`;

export default Home;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'react-scroll-trigger';

function MyComponent() {
  const triggerRef = useRef(null);


useEffect(() => {

    const current = triggerRef.current;

    current.addEventListener("enter", () => {
      // do something
    });
    current.addEventListener("leave", () => {
      // do something
    });
    return () => {
      current.removeEventListener("enter", () => {});
      current.removeEventListener("leave", () => {});
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ScrollTrigger ref={triggerRef}>
      <MyContent />
      </ScrollTrigger>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: please give me another solution